# Python multithreading sqlite3 inserts

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I would like to make a program with multiple threads. In each thread should be a database INSERT.

**EDIT**

But now I get the same error after a time

My code:

```
import threading, sqlite3



class myThread(threading.Thread):


   def __init__(self, pn, icm):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.pn = pn
       self.icm = icm


   def run(self):

       con = sqlite3.connect("DB.db", check_same_thread=False)
       cursor = con.cursor()
       cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(pn VARCHAR(100), icm VARCHAR(100))")
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('"+self.pn+"', '"+self.icm+"')")
       con.commit()
       con.close()


for i in range(0, 300):
   myThread("ABCDEFG", "1234546").start()
```

I get the ERROR:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Thank you,
Jay

Comment: What went wrong?

Comment: @tdelaney      Edited

Comment: As the error message says. You close the database with `con.close()`. That is why it cannot write / execute query on your database. You need to reconnect, usually with `sqlite3.connect()`.

Comment: You can not do multiple writes to an SQLite database at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

**Answered**

```
import threading
import time, sqlite3


class myThread(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, pn, icm):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.pn = pn
       self.icm = icm

       self.con = sqlite3.connect("DB.db", check_same_thread=False)
       self.cursor = self.con.cursor()
       self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, pn VARCHAR(100), icm VARCHAR(100))")



   def run(self):

       self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(NULL, '"+self.pn+"', '"+self.icm+"')")
       self.con.commit()
       self.con.close()



for i in range(0, 300):

    myThread("ABCDEFG", "12345678").start()
```